# Skype (linux) won't connect after being killed by signal -9

Tags: linux, skype

Sometimes i kill apps using killall -9, including Skype. This is usually not an issue, but sometimes Skype doesn't connect to a network until i reboot a machine. It starts, then infinitely performing its "connecting..." animation after i entered login/password. Erasing the ~/.Skype doesn't helps. Seems to be Skype has something very survivable that keeps some kind of state of something (like shared memory descriptor/state) between skype's launches. What can it be? What i should try to "rm"/reset/clean? What i should write to what system variable?

I know: killall -9 is unusual procedure, skype is a "one giant bug" and so on. But this is kind of research for me: why that could be happening.

Comment: `kill -9` shouldn't be used routinely. See http://superuser.com/questions/354784/adverse-consequences-of-using-kill-9-for-skype-termination

Comment: If you have to do this “sometimes” and `killall` isn’t working, uninstall Skype, because it may be behaving like one giant bug.

Comment: @minitech killall is working perfectly. The problem is in next launches.

Comment: `killall` by itself. `-9` is KILL. Default is TERM. Use TERM.

Comment: @minitech the question is not about using `killall` properly :)